# Drag-n-drop geometry that consists of polylines

Tags: javascript, arcgis

I have a geometry that consists of polylines. I need to create a drag and drop function for this geometry. How is this best implemented?

I created a click listener and recalculate the coordinates of all Polylines in relation to the location of the click with each new click. But I would like to implement drag and drop. Maybe Arcgis has some native function for this case?

```
export function newCoord(polyline, newLonLat){
    return polyline.map(i => [i[0] + newLonLat[0], i[1] + newLonLat[1]]);
}


view.on("click", function (evt) {
    const evtProps = view.toMap({x: evt.x, y: evt.y});
    geometry.forEach(i => newCoord(i, [evtProps.longitude, evtProps.latitude]));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arcgis has a [SketchViewModel](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Sketch-SketchViewModel.html) widget that lets you load and editing Graphics after added to the map.

And we can saving graphics after editing, using method sketchViewModel

```
sketchViewModel.on("update",  () =>{
localStorage.setItem('features', geometryGraphics.toJSON())
})
```

for example.